# Node.js - what is the boot() function and where it is from?

Tags: node.js, bootstrapping, helper

I'm new in Node.js development and I'm exploring the code of a real project (using Node.js, Express, Typescript). There is this code:

```
import { boot, bootOptions } from './helpers/bootstrap';

const opts = bootOptions();

boot(opts).then(createRestRoutes()).then(restRoutes => {

    // Register routes (as middleware layer through express.Router())
    app.use(restRoutes);
    ...
}
```

The boot() function is defined in `bootstrap.ts` file in `src/helpers` directory. I've never seen this function used in examples during my study of Node.js/express. I've tried to google it but found nothing relevant (except for Bootstrap CSS framework).

Could you please explain to me where that function/file came from and where it is documented? Is it a third-party file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bootstrap.ts` - is custom module, not a library.
So, your `boot` function can be whatever a developer wished.

Just open that file and examine it.